# How to Generate Thumbnail from AWS S3 Media Cache Source in Wowza

Tags: wowza, wowza-transcoder

Could anyone let me know how to generate thumbnail from AWS S3 media cache source?

I stream videos directly from AWS S3 bucket and want to find a way to generate a thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Base on AWS. You can use Amazon Elastic Transcoder https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/details/

> Thumbnails: **Amazon Elastic Transcoder can generate thumbnails** of your
>   output video for you. You can set the size of the thumbnails, aspect
>   ratio and other parameters including how many thumbnails you would
>   like to have generated. Generating multiple thumbnails is useful if
>   you want to add chapter markers, provide a visual scan function or
>   simply choose the most representative thumbnail for your content.

Another way. You can use ffmpeg to [generate thumbnails](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Cheers,
Patrick

Comment: Please refrain from leaving link-only answers. You can add the crux of what the link says to the answer.